# Unable to find the class 'Common'

Tags: sonicmq

I am new to Sonic and am trying out Management API.

I took the program ShowQueues.java inside Sonic_Installation\MQ8.6\samples\Management\runtimeAPI\javaProxy and pasted it into eclipse, since I want to change the url (currently: tcp://localhost:2506).

It is showing an error near the class 'Common'. Can you please tell me which jar this 'Common' class is available in?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Common class is part of the sample project and can be found in the sample directory.

> SonicHome\MQ8.6\samples\Management\runtimeAPI\javaProxyCommon.java
>   -- utility methods used by the above samples

Otherwise the jars  can be found in the lib directory.

The class path for the Mgmt api is :

> MGMT_CLASSPATH=%SONICMQ_LIB%\mgmt_client.jar;%SONICMQ_LIB%\mgmt_config.jar;%SONICMQ_LIB%\mfcontext.jar;%SONICMQ_LIB%\xercesImpl.jar

The class path for the MQ api is :

> SONICMQ_CLASSPATH=%SONICMQ_LIB%\sonic_Client.jar;%SONICMQ_LIB%\sonic_mgmt_client.jar

Regards